# uuidExtra is null How to convert that to String

Tags: java, android

See `String uuids` My CODE :

```
if (uuidExtra != null) {
   for (Parcelable p : uuidExtra) {
       String uuids = ""+p;
   }
}
```

I'm not programmer. I just learning about it.

Comment: What are you asking for? How is this related to android?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Unfortunately this post is completely unclear and as @FailingCoder commented, doesn't include a question. Please edit the question so that SO contributors can respond effectively. Visit SO Help Center and the section on 'Asking' for more guidelines >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Hi. Can you underline your question??

Answer (score 0):

Can you underline you question here?
Do you want to know what is the result of your `uuids` variable?

If so, the result will be the latest data of your `uuidExtra`. Because in line 3, you make new variable of `uuids`.

To make it more clear, let me give some example :

You have a List of string. Let's say `a,b,c,d,e`. Then you access every index of that List using `for`. Inside that for, you make a new variable called `uuids`. The problem is, you make new variable everytime doing a loop. So the result is `uuids = e`.

If you want to have result like this `uuids = a,b,c,d,e`. You need to modify your code like this.

```
String uuids;
if (uuidExtra != null) {
   for (Parcelable p : uuidExtra) {
       uuids = ""+p;
   }
}
```